# Who was the girl in Django unchained?

Tags: character, django-unchained

Who was the blue eyed women in the blue mask, seen twice in the *Django Unchained*; once when they rode into Candyland and the other when it is night and she is looking through a magnifying glass at a photo of a black girl? There is no reference to her in the movie at all.

Comment: +1 good question... her appearance definitely suggested there was more to her story, so indeed it seemed strange when her character was left unexplored

Comment: A screenshot of a scene? Time in a film?

Answer (score 24):

> Zoe Bell, who starred for Tarantino in "Death Proof," played another
>   character that was seemingly cut down -- one of the plantation
>   enforcers who wears a bandana over her face and earns a third-act
>   close-up.
>
> "Yeah, you don’t really get anything from her character,” Goggins
>   said. “But she’s lethal. And you know, I should probably just stick to
>   myself and my character.”
>
> Speaking to E! on the red carpet at the premiere of "Hansel And
>   Gretel: Witch Hunters," Bell revealed what happened with her role.
>
> "There was backstory and there was to be a fight sequence," she said.
>   "I don't know how much Quentin wants me to say, but yes, there was
>   originally more than that."
>
> According to Bell, her scenes weren't even shot. Which is too bad.
>
> "There was a little sneaky secret under the mask: part of my face was
>   missing."

[Interview with Zoe Bell about her role in Django Unchained](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/01/28/django-unchained-script-zoe-bell_n_2567640.html)

Comment: So many answers and no one googled this. I don't understand it was the first hit.

Comment: That's funny - for the sake of a word I probably missed this interview when I did my digging - ah well - between us all we have a bloody comprehensive answer ;)